# Definitions in flex lexical analyzer - How to define scientific notation

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I'm new to using flex and need to define real literal numbers, ie. 3.1 or 3.0e-10 as acceptable numbers. Here is what I have so far:

```
digit       [0-9]
int     {digit}+
real_literal  ({digit}+)("."{digit}*)
```

From my understanding this works for decimals without accepting something like 12.52.23

How would I define numbers that accept scientific notation, such as 3.0e-10 like mentioned above?

Would it be something like this?

```
real_literal  ({digit}+)("."{digit}*)|({digit}+)("."{digit})[Ee]["-""+"]{digit}+
```

Comment: `["+""-"]` is a character class that accepts one of the three characters `"`, `+` or `-`. Most characters, including `"`, have no special meaning inside character class brackets. See [the flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns) (short but assues you know something about regular expressions) or any basic guide to regular expressions (but check with the flex manual for idiosyncracies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution, a bit shorter than yours, would be:

```
{digit}+"."{digit}*([eE][-+]?{digit}+)?
```

**Break down**

- `{digit}+"."{digit}` matches positive real numbers (it won't recognize integers).
- `(...)?` enclosing the next part in parenthesis followed by a question mark makes what's inside optional.
- `[eE][-+]?{digit}+` match the exponent. Note that the `-` is not escaped within squared brackets **in this case** because it's the first or last character of the list, as @rici pointed out.

I just want to point out that you're not recognizing negative numbers here, but I don't know if that's intentional.

Comment: Both `[-+]` and `[+-]` work fine, because `-` is not special when it's the first or last symbol inside the brackets. That's the case in most regex libraries, too. But it should be `[+-]?` since `1.0e7` is correct, too.